# How to use al_draw_bitmap_region?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, allegro5

my code keeps breaking in my render section, after trying to draw the bitmap region. What things do i need to check to make sure that the background map works?

Comment: Please include a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: ```ALLEGRO_BITMAP* bmp = al_load_bitmap("image.png");if (!bmp) {Fail();}```